# Read only ints with BufferedReader from text file - Java

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader

So if I have a txt file like this:

```
scissors 3
papers 5
staplers 2
```

How do I only read the integers with a bufferedreader and not using scan.

```
try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Supplies.txt"));

        String line = "";
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);            
    }
```

Comment: You can't avoid reading the line and once you read line, you can parse the line to get the integer.

Comment: A question like "How do I this and that" is too broad. Where exactly so you have a problem? You are already reading the lines. So simply extract the numbers from them.

Answer (score 0):

*How do I only read the integers with a bufferedreader and not using scan.*

Assuming I understand your question, you could use your current code, and add a regular expression to remove everything that isn't a digit before parsing the `int` value. Like,

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(line.replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

You ***should*** `close()` your `reader` when you finish with it, otherwise you leak a file handle. I believe the best solution is a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Like,

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Supplies.txt"))) {
    // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Supplies.txt"));
```